# Linux or Windows version of a library in Cygwin?

Tags: serialization, boost, g++, cygwin

I have developed some codes in Linux which use `boost::serialization` library. Now I want to copy my files into Cygwin and compile them to produce executable for Windows. I know that I should use Mingw-64 g++ compiler. But how about boost library? Should I download the Windows version or the Linux version of this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cygwin, you install Boost libraries as per Unix/Linux. From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

> Getting Started on Windows
>
> A note to Cygwin and MinGW users
>
> If you plan to use your tools from the Windows command prompt, you're in the right place.
> If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually running on a POSIX
> platform and should follow the instructions for getting started on Unix variants.
> Other command shells, such as MinGW's MSYS, are not supported—they may or may not work.